# Polymorphic map keys in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am working on a computer vision API where I have various algorithms that all work on image data and attempt to classify some objects.

Some of the algorithms are simple which say classify objects simply based on their size ie. the algorithm might return the count of all objects based on their size like small, medium, big, for example

Some other algorithms are more fine tuned and may classify objects based on their true type for example like table, chair, bed.

So I have an interface for all such counting objects as:

```
class IFurnitureCounter
{
    virtual std::map<ObjectType, size_t> getCount(const Image &input) = 0;
};
```

The idea is that each of these algorithms will implement this `getCount()` method so that the caller can use them agnostically.

My issue is that the `ObjectType` key becomes a mish mash. So, I can define this `ObjectType` as an enum for example:

```
enum class ObjectType {SMALL, MEDIUM, BIG, TABLE, CHAIR, BED}
```

However this feels bad as each algorithm now sees all the types even though a particular algorithm might only work on a subset of them. I was wondering if there is a better deisgn paradigm to have a better decoupling of these types between algorithms.

**EDIT**
One thing that I thought about is have different enum for different algorithms and specialise over that type.

So, say we have something like:

```
enum class SizeEnum {SMALL, MEDIUM, BIG};
enum class ObjectTypeEnum {CHAIR, TABLE, BENCH}
```

So, my interface could look like:

```
template<typename EnumType>
class IFurnitureCounter
{
    virtual std::map<EnumType, size_t> getCount(const Image &input) = 0;
};
```

Now I could have something like:

```
class MyAwesomeCounter: public IFurnitureCounter<ObjectTypeEnum>
{
   // My implementation here...
};
```

Would something like this work? Maybe my syntax is not accurate but can someone tell me if this is a reasonable approach or not?

Comment: I think you probably want to take look at visitor pattern but but your count of all objects is confusing, because does the function operate on one object or multiple?

Comment: @zar thanks for the comment. Sorry my interface was incomplete and I fixed that. So basically the function operates on an image which may contain multiple objects/classes and hence I was returning a dictionary of detected classes with their counts. Could you elaborate a bit on how the visitor patterm might be useful. In the end the caller needs to know the detected classes in the image and their counts agnostically independent of the underlying implementation.

Comment: Are chairs and cars and kittens hardcoded into your program? I'd imagine they should be loaded from some kind of data.

Comment: @n.m. The labels are defined by us and could be loaded or even defined with an enumeration as I have done but yes they could come from some configuration but it is more likely than the code will be updated with some enumeration type.

Comment: When you say an image can have multiple objects, that means this could be a composite pattern.

Comment: @zar I meant multiple objects/labels could be detected in the image. There is no reason for these labels to be treated as separate objects with any functionality. They simply describe which label a pixel in the image takes. It would be too cumbersome and a maintainance nightmare if one had o create a C++ class for each possible label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a valid approach but I found a template based approach that seems to work (at least from C++ 11 on).

```
// Interface class
template<typename EnumType>
class IFurnitureCounter
{
public:
    virtual std::map<EnumType, size_t> getCount() = 0;
};
```

Now we can inherit from the base as:

```
enum class ObjectTypeEnum {CHAIR, TABLE, BENCH};
class MyAwesomeCounter: public IFurnitureCounter<ObjectTypeEnum>
{
public:
    virtual std::map<ObjectTypeEnum, size_t> getCount()
    {
         ObjectTypeEnum ote = ObjectTypeEnum::CHAIR;
         std::map<ObjectTypeEnum, size_t> map;
         map[ote] = 5;
         return map;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyAwesomeCounter mac = MyAwesomeCounter();
    auto r = mac.getCount();
    std::cout << r[ObjectTypeEnum::CHAIR] << std::endl;
}
```

The seems to do the job. I am sure there are downfalls to this approach and I look forward to any comments one might have.

This code can be run here: http://www.cpp.sh/8h5uy